# Orthnormalization of the system $(1,t,t^2) $ in $C[0,2\pi]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Is the  orthonormalization of the system:

$${1,t,t^2}$$ in $C[0,2\pi]$ with $(f,g)=\int fg $ as scalarproduct

given by :

$$v_1= 1 $$

$$v_2 = t- \frac{\int_0^{2\pi} 1\cdot t \, dt }{\int_0^{2\pi}1\cdot 1 \, dt } \cdot 1  = t-\frac{2\pi ^2}{2\pi } = t-\pi$$

$$v_3 = t^2 - \frac{\int_0^{2\pi}t^2 t \, dt }{\int_0^{2\pi}(t-\pi)(t-\pi) \, dt }t - \frac{\int_0^{2\pi}t^2 1 \, dt}{\int_0^{2\pi} 1\cdot 1 \, dt}1 = t^2 - (6\pi)(t-\pi) - \frac{4}{3}\pi ^2  $$

correct? $((v_1,v_2)=(v_2,v_3)=(v_3,v_1)=0$ and for the normalization one would divide each of the vectors by their norm : $||f||:= (f,f)^{1/2}$

Does the scalar product always have to be taken in the interval boundaries of the space that is given? Is there a faster way to orthonormalize a system than Gram-Schmidt?

Comment: The inner product should be taken on the full interval, otherwise you could define a function $f$, which is different from $0$, but $\langle f, f\rangle = 0$

Comment: Consider using Jacobi polynomials.